# How to correct the exclusion list for Time Machine backup? Music is not listed for exclusion, but is excluded

Tags: time-machine

I'm running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 and have noticed the Music folder is not listed for exclusion. However, this folder is not actually backed up, as I can see this by going into the backup disk, it is not there.

[image]

This is confirmed by looking at the exclusion list which has Music there for some reason:

[image]

Any idea what went wrong? A bug? Or the exclusion list somehow inherited this from previous settings of the Time Machine I must have had in the past, I may have excluded Music some years ago? Is it possible to rectify this?

Comment: Note it not the Music directory that is excluded but some files and directories in it - This does not really alter the question

Comment: I'd try toggling the bit, so to speak, by adding the Music folder to the exclusion list in Time Machine, logout, login and then remove it from the exclusion list. Add something new to your Music folder and then run a Time Machine backup. Does it backup the newly added item(s) now?

Comment: @Mark   I think it is the whole directory as it is missing in the backup completely, otherwise at least something would be under ~/Music.

Comment: @user3439894  I was also thinking of toggling this, but decided to ask first as it could have been as simple as just editing some input file which time machine is using. May be it is that simple? Then it would be straightforward (provided it is a text file).

Comment: @user3439894 I removed ~/Music, checked with sudo mdfind "com_apple_backup_excludeItem = 'com.apple.backupd'"

Comment: @user3439894 I removed ~/Music, checked with "com_apple_backup_excludeItem = 'com.apple.backupd'" and then removed it running the command again. The same result. It seems, that this information is held somewhere and is not updated. Moreover, I tried to remove some random files, and rerun the command, it did not show any difference, so may be it does not pick up all the exclusions. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

These are not the files from the exclusion list but files that have been directly marked as excluded in their extended attributes.

For example:

```
$ xattr "/Users/foo/Music/iTunes/Album Artwork/Cache"
com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem
```

Most of these seem to be logs, caches or indexes that can be rebuilt.